# Solving 3-SAT in O(n^6)?

Tags: sat, polynomial-time, upper-bounds

There's an algorithm (published on [GitHub](https://github.com/danvoicu1/nanosat/blob/main/PvsNP.pdf)) which is claimed to solve any 3-SAT formulation in polynomial time with a complexity of max O(n^6). I would usually brush claims like this away, but having looked at the code I found the approach worth a try, especially as the author provided a reference implementation and tested it exhaustively.

The author's reference implementation is in C#, so I ported it to C++ to run it on Linux and tested his algorithm on a lot of instances, from pure random generated instances over (hard) [Barthel](https://algo2.iti.kit.edu/balyo/papers/socs18slides.pdf) instances (Clause Distribution Control (CDC) based with r=4.3) up to hard industrial combinatoric instances - all of these have been correctly solved with less than n^6 steps. But why?

I'm scratching my head why the proposed algorithm performs that well. The main idea is comparable to a vertex cover problem search, but the best algorithms I have seen so far usually have exponential complexity, and cannot solve 3SAT in O(n^6). Based on the code there's indeed a maximum runtime of n^6 steps implemented.

I'm wondering if anyone here could provide a mathematical explanation (for the empirical demonstrated) performance (or if there are any pitfalls) and if it holds (generalised) for any 3-SAT problem.

Really appreciate your thoughts!

Comment: How big are these "hard" instances? I can fit an exponential curve to a curve of order 6 up to pretty large values.

Comment: @DanielM: if the author has a promising implementation of SAT, they can compete in SAT solver competitions, e.g., http://www.satcompetition.org/. That would provide good evidence that their algorithm is empirically efficient.

Comment: Would you share your C++ port? This may be interesting to test.

Answer (score 7):

You can find all weird stuff out there...
For example, just google "graph isomorphism problem 2022", and the first search result is this polytime algorithm... https://www.biorxiv.org/content/10.1101/2022.04.14.488296v1.full
and result number six: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/360300519_Solving_graph_isomorphism_problem_in_polynomial_time_using_liner_algebra
Also, I've seen publications that are so confusing that it takes days to understand why they have a "gap"...